# Utilizando variável na função chdir (módulo OS)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Seria possível utilizar o dado informado em uma variável em alguma outra função sem ser a **chdir()** do módulo **OS** do Python?

Percebi que não é possível utilizar variáveis na troca de diretórios utilizando esse método. Teria outro do tipo? (pode ser de outro módulo inclusive).

A ideia seria assim:

```
import os

def mudardir():
    a = 'Python'
    os.chdir('C:/Users/','a','diretoriob')

 mudardir()
```

Como eu não sei qual é o nome de usuário e a variável do próprio Windows **%userprofile%** não é aceita pelo método, então pensei em definir já anteriormente para depois utilizar dentro da função!

Desde já sou grato pela atenção de todos!

Comment: "Percebi que não é possível utilizar variáveis na troca de diretórios utilizando esse método." <- Pode dizer de onde tirou essa conclusão? Além disso, o seu uso do método `os.chdir` não parece estar correto. Essa função recebe apenas um argumento, mas você está passando três.

Comment: Na verdade está recebendo três argumentos porque eu acrescentei a variável "a" ali no meio para explicar a ideia de como eu gostaria que ficasse. Caso contrário ficaria somente um ('C:/Users/Python/diretoriob') que é o correto...

Comment: Aliás consegui resolver o problema. Consegui utilizar o dado da variável passando ela como parâmetro na função!

Comment: Então o que é 'a'? É o diretório pai do diretoriob?

Comment: Certo. Coloque sua solução como resposta.

Comment: Exatamente. Porém no meu script em alguns casos eu não saberia o nome deste diretório pai, por isso antes de utilizar o método os.chdir eu precisaria informar em uma variável qual seria o nome dele... Aí então surgiu a dúvida de como eu faria para acrescentar uma variável no argumento, já que o método aceita somente um, e com o uso da variável ficaria mais de um.

Comment: "Certo. Coloque sua solução como resposta." ->  Eu sou iniciante aqui do SOF. Como posso informar a solução? Basta somente responder ao meu próprio tópico?

Comment: Era só trocar as vírgulas por + e tirar as aspas do 'a'. Sim, pode responder sua própria pergunta como se fosse a de outra pessoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recuperar o diretório do usuário você pode utilizar a biblioteca [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser), exemplo:

```
from os.path import expanduser
user_dir = expanduser("~")
print(user_dir)
```

A saída em *Windows* será semelhante:

```
'C:\\Users\\Thon'
```

[image: Windows]

A saída em *Linux* será semelhante:

```
/home/wmsouza
```

> Podes ver funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DarkgreenLightcoralMullet).

Ou pode utilizar a biblioteca [`pathlib.Path.home()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home) disponível em *Python 3.5+*.

```
from pathlib import Path
user_dir = str(Path.home())
print(user_dir)
```

> Podes ver funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/HappyVioletCopepod).

Sabendo-se isto, basta adicionar um parâmetro em seu método:

```
import os
from os.path import expanduser

def mudardir(diretorio):
    user_dir = expanduser("~")
    os.chdir(user_dir + diretorio)

# Em meu computador seria algo assim
# /home/wmsouza/Python
mudardir('/Python')
# /home/wmsouza/Python/Projeto_A
mudardir('/Python/Projeto_A')
# /home/wmsouza/Python/Projeto_B
mudardir('/Python/Projeto_B')
```

Answer (score -1):

## eu fiz + ou - assim

## não precisa fazer o def, só uma variável com o usuário e o diretório

def cd(diretorio, usuario):
    os.chdir("c:/users/" + usuario + "/" + diretorio + "")